# Device orientation in Xcode does not seem to work properly

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape

In my project I have only options "portrait" and "upside down" selected. The two of landscape options are not checked. But when I run it whether on a device or on simulator and turn it right or left the app becomes landscape. It should not, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ups, sorry i didn't noticed the iPad tab which also containes checkboxes with checked landscape